# How to watch all .js files with npx, and have output file be one directory above original react .js file?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, npx

I am trying to create a web React app that has multiple pages. I was able to configure babel so that it watches a single directory and output the vanilla Javascript files one directory above. The problem is that I have multiple folders with React files, and I do not want to manually have a watch command for each directory. I was wondering if I was able to do this with one command that watches all js/react/ directories and outputs to the respective js/ directories.

```
//node_modules have been excluded for brevity
.
├── app.js
├── environment.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── colab
│   │   ├── create
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   │   │   ├── main.js
│   │   │   ├── project.js
│   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   │   │   ├── js
│   │   │   │   └── react
│   │   │   │       ├── main.js
│   │   │   │       └── project.js
│   │   │   ├── style.css
│   │   │   └── test.json
│   │   └── navbar
│   └── homepage
│       ├── css
│       │   └── style.css
│       ├── images
│       │   ├── bixby.png
│       │   ├── fortniteskill.png
│       │   ├── turtle.png
│       │   └── turtle2.jpg
│       ├── index.html
│       └── js
│           └── react
                └── main.js
└── routers
    ├── alexa.js
    ├── api.js
    ├── colab.js
    └── home.js
```

`npx babel --watch . --out-dir js/ --presets react-app/prod`